# Can we write a Nextflow script that executes Multiple Nextflow scripts?

Tags: pipeline, bioinformatics, nextflow

Instead of having one huge Nextflow script that run all the pipelines.
To make to easier to read the file and edit pipeline down the road.
Can we write a Nextflow script that executes Multiple Nextflow scripts?

Answer (score 4):

The new [DSL2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) lets you define [modules](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#modules) which can contain workflow components (i.e. functions, processes and worflows) which can be imported into another Nextflow script using the `include` keyword. The [module inclusion](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-inclusion) example in the docs has a typo, but it should look like:

```
include { foo } from './some/module.nf'

workflow {
    data = channel.fromPath('/some/data/*.txt')
    foo(data)
}
```

> The above snippet includes a process with name `foo` defined in the
> module script in the main execution context. This way, `foo` can be
> invoked in the `workflow` scope.
>
> Nextflow implicitly looks for the script file `./some/module.nf`
> resolving the path against the *including* script location.