# Best way to combine Nextflow pipelines within Nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I'm new to NextFlow and I wonder which is the best way to call NextFlow pipelines within my new pipeline? I know I can call processes individually, but I'm interested in calling the overall pipeline so I can combine multiple nf scripts.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Can we write a Nextflow script that executes Multiple Nextflow scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480750/can-we-write-a-nextflow-script-that-executes-multiple-nextflow-scripts)

Comment: I know I can call modules from other pipelines, however I'm more interested in calling the  whole pipeline directly.

Answer (score 1):

That's what we call subworkflows. In DSL2, the default DSL for Nextflow currently, you can have numerous workflow entries in your `.nf` workflow file. With that, you can not only call these subworkflows (named workflow entries) from the main workflow (unnamed), but also from the CLI with `-entry workflow-name`.

You can also import workflows from other `.nf` files to your current one, the same way you do with modules. This way, your default unnamed workflow can also run the workflow block of other `.nf` files.

Let's say you have a pipeline that does A (with many processes within it), another pipeline B (with many processes within it) and you have a pipeline C in which you'd like to call these two from within it. Import the processes/workflows from A and B and call them from your unnamed workflow block in C.